# Нумерация в PEP

Tags: python, pep

Как я понимаю, нумерация PEP растет вверх как только появляются какие либо обновления?
Или, все таки, каждый номер PEP отвечает за себя?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вот список [peps](https://github.com/python/peps) - как видите, нумерация не последовательная и может назначаться как вздумается.

Например, [PEP 754](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0754/) получил такой номер, потому что описывал работу чисел с плавающей точкой IEEE 754 и предлагающему показалось уместным дать ему такой номер.

Вот ещё пример: [PEP 628](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0628/) - предложение добавить математическую константу tau (2π), которая примерно равна 6.28.